# Conditional clause to describe a same situation, but possible for some people, and impossible for others?

Tags: conditionals

There are three types of conditional clause:

1. **First conditional:** use in possible condition
   If I have enough money, I will go to Japan.
2. **Second conditional:** use in unhappened condition
   If I had enough money, I would go to Japan.
3. **Third conditional:** use in unreal but wish to happened condition
   If I had had enough money, I would have gone to Japan.

Consider this sentence:

> If we only needed to talk to people in our country, it would be needless to learn new languages.

I am writing this sentence in a learning language website. In that context, we can **assume** that *everyone* will talk to people from other countries, so I can conclude that the otherwise is an unhappened condition, therefore the second conditional is best to use. However, it is not true that everyone will have to do that, so it is possible to use first conditional. In short, for some people, not going to talk in a foreign language is possible, while for other it's impossible. The conditional to use would be 1.5, if it existed.

Is there a way to transmit this meaning?

Comment: Just because you use **would** doesn't necessarily mean it is always **conditional**. You can safely say "If we only need to talk to ..., it would be ..." unless you are using **second conditional** in your definition.

Comment: thanks, that's the I'm looking for. I (and the site) will (or would?) be glad if you make it an answer